# Why useState cause the dom to render twice

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple hello-world example to try out `useState` hook; however when I output testing information in console, I found that whenever I enabled `useState` the console logs twice the information.

see [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-dust-zjw2e?file=/src/App.js) in CodeSandbox (debug info is shown in console).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The console statement is in function body, `React` will execute the function body on each render.

1. On component mount , As the init state is empty, the console will print an empty  string.
2. As you are updating the the state on component Mount, `React` will execute the function body again and then log the state with the updated value.

> As you are using the `React.StrictMode` it can render the component more than once. That is the reason you see the console logs multiple times.
>
> The commit phase is usually very fast, but rendering can be slow. For this reason, the upcoming concurrent mode (which is not enabled by default yet) breaks the rendering work into pieces, pausing and resuming the work to avoid blocking the browser. This means that React may invoke render phase lifecycles more than once before committing, or it may invoke them without committing at all (because of an error or a higher priority interruption).
>   Render phase lifecycles include the following class component methods:
>
> 1. constructor
>
>    2. componentWillMount (or UNSAFE_componentWillMount)
>    3. componentWillReceiveProps (or UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps)
>    4. componentWillUpdate (or UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate)
>    5. getDerivedStateFromProps
>    6. shouldComponentUpdate render
>    7. setState updater functions (the first argument)
>
> **Because the above methods might be called more than once**, it’s important that they do not contain side-effects. Ignoring this rule can lead to a variety of problems, including memory leaks and invalid application state. Unfortunately, it can be difficult to detect these problems as they can often be non-deterministic.

You can read more about `React.StrictMode` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

useEffect runs asynchronously , so at the beginning , first of all react render the component as its normal behavior and then useEffect runs , and as we know each setState will causes the component to re-render and it's the second time , this is why you see it log twice

Answer (score 1):

Your index.js has app component wrapper with React.StrictMode.

This is what is causing it.